# How to run multiple emulators from shell?

Tags: shell, android-emulator

In order to run one emulator, I use command

```
emulator -avd my_emulator_name &
```

If I want to automatically run 2 (or more) emulators via shell this way:

```
emulator -avd my_emulator_name1 &
emulator -avd my_emulator_name2 &
```

none of emulators will start. As soon as I start next emulator, the previous crashes.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those guys on linux can make a shell script like this and run it each time from desktop.

1. make empty file `lauchTablets.sh`
2. copy the code into it

   echo "Running 1"
   emulator -avd emu1 &
   sleep 5s;
   echo "done!"

   echo "Running 2"
   emulator -avd emu2 &
   sleep 5s;
   echo "done!"

   echo "Running 3"
   emulator -avd emu3 &
   sleep 5s;
   echo "done!"

   echo "Running 4"
   emulator -avd emu4
   echo "done!"
3. make the file executable

I set sleep period of 5 seconds randomly. you may try with lower sleep interval.